# AS3: String to cookie?

Tags: actionscript-3, cookies

In my Flash game, when an enemy dies, I want to increase a Flash cookie by one. Different enemies cause different cookies to be increased, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that.

On each enemy's class file, I have a public string variable called "CookieName." When an enemy dies, which is handled by a class called GameScript, I'm trying to use code that's something like this:

```
[enemy.enemy.CookieName]+=1;
```

That way, if an Enemy1 dies, gameStats.data.Enemy1sKilled should be raised by 1, and if an Enemy2 dies, gameStats.data.Enemy2sKilled should be raised by 1.

The issue is that it doesn't seem to be working. I think the problem might be my syntax. Any ideas on how I should do this, or is there a better way that I should be doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're after:

```
if(gameStats.data[CookieName] === undefined)
{
    gameStats.data[CookieName] = 0;
}

gameStats.data[CookieName] += 1;
```

Comment: gameStats.data[enemy.enemy.CookieName] += 1; seems to work. Thanks!